# How can I select a div if another div exists in DOM

Tags: html, css

I have this sample:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NwmPJa

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="product-info-main">
  <div class="product-add-form">
    <div class="qty">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="product-social-links">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.qty + .product-social-links{
      background: red;
}
```

why does not this CSS code go?
I really want to apply the style only if the `.qty` div exists.

How can I do this without javascript, just from CSS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `product-social-links` is not a sibling of `qty`. You will not be able to do this with CSS

Comment: CSS can't go from children to parents, impossible to do something like `.qty < parent + sibling {styles}`. Only way when this code is generated is to add class `.has-qty` to `.product-info-main`, than `.has-qty + .product-social-links` will work. Other way is to use JS.

Comment: `+` means to select *adjacent sibling`*

Comment: You cant as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: or wait for CSS 4 and you will you will have parent selector :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you mentioned which is  `.qty + .product-social-links` will not work because `.qty` does not have the same parent as `.product-social-links`. They should have the same parent for this to work. A better solution would be to set the parent which is the same level as `.product-social-links`.

See solution below:

```
.product-info-main + .product-social-links {
background: red;
}
```